# RegEx to remove legacy CRLF from SMTP message

Tags: regex, smtp

Due to some legacy standard when you send an email from Outlook the plain text format includes a `CRLF` or `\r\n` every *n*-characters.

In the app I'm writing I'd like to display this plain text **without** the added line breaks, so that text wrapping works and I can take full advantage of the screen size.

Outlook, for example, removes these "unnecessary" line break automatically, and I'm trying to write a regex to do the same but struggling with the format.

From what I can tell outlook does its parsing as follows:

- Removes CRLF only on lines with text which does not have a `' '` (`\s`) at the end prior to the `CRLF`.

Assistance on how to parse this in regex would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You seem to have a good starting point. Read up on regex.

Comment: The proper fix is to MIME-encode your plain-text part in quoted-printable or base64.  See also the `format=flowed` spec for `text/plain` MIME parts (starting point: http://joeclark.org/ffaq.html).  You really cannot be worrying about line endings in the raw message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?<! )\s$
```

That will match a single whitespace character at the end of the line which is not preceeded by a space. Note that you need to have the multiline flag in your regex, or this will only match at the end of the total string.